# Intellisense adding namespace and class name to enum

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellisense

This is more of an annoyance than an issue but either way its driving me nuts.

Whenever Im setting or comparing an enum value (Lets use DialogResult as an example), Intellisense is giving me the enum with the namespace name, even if the namespace is referenced. And I like nice clean code so I cant just leave it like that.

Im pretty sure that this is happening with DialogResult because a windows Form has a property called DialogResult. But this never happened in earlier versions of VS. I looked through the Intellisense option but I didnt find anything.

[image: screenshot]

I know this is very trivial but if anyone has a fix or any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Upgrade to 2015...problem solved

Comment: @BrandonSeydel You are correct, the issue does not happen in 2015, Thank you. Honestly I didnt know 2015 was even out and I especially didnt know it was free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Upgraded to VS2015 and now its fine.